# how to set screen orientation from non main activity in android

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

I'm a beginner in android development

I want to set `screen orientation` from non main `activity`

I have 2 classes :-

1. public class `MainActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity`

In `MainActivity` have this `method` :-

```
public void setOrintation(){

if (My_Values.STABLE_MODE_ENABLE == 1) {

        int orientation = this.getRequestedOrientation();
        int rotation = ((WindowManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            default:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
        }
        this.setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    } else {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    }
}
```

2. `public class My_View extends View implements View.OnTouchListener` (Non inside class)

then I can't call `MainActivity` `setOrintation()` method

how to do this any way?

Comment: I think you can use `getContext()` instead of `this` in a VIew

Comment: so did it, but it did not happen.

Comment: method is not static if method is static main activity cannot set this.setRequestedOrientation(orientation);

Comment: create another class, add there this method as static, pass a Context as a parameter, and use that context in the method

Comment: this method setRequestedOrientation(orientation); not possible work with static method.

Comment: each method belongs to some class. Do you know which class does `setRequestedOrientation` method belong to?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to create interface with metod setOrintation(), and let MainActivity implements this interface. And in My_View object you'll have to send activity as this interface